# Visual C++ project developed in Visual C++ 2005 - In Visual C++ 2010, debug assertion fails on menu open, but release mode works, how to fix?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc

I just started working on a project that was developed in Visual C++ 2005 using MFC, by someone else. To do so, I installed Visual C++ 2010 - I have no experience using either version (or visual studio at all, for that matter).

The application has a menu bar that is implemented using the `CMenu` class, and is initialized from a resource (ie, is created using the menu editor).

If I run the application in debug mode, the following debug assertion fails as soon as I open any menu in the menu bar:

Filename: `afxwin1.inl`

Assertion (with appropriate context):

```
    _AFXWIN_INLINE HMENU CMenu::GetSafeHmenu() const
        { ASSERT(this == NULL || m_hMenu == NULL || ::IsMenu(m_hMenu));
            return this == NULL ? NULL : m_hMenu; }
```

According to the debugger, `this` is set to a pointer to my menu, and `this->m_hMenu` is set to a pointer as well - however, the debugger seems to be confused about the type, the value is `0xdeadbeef {unused=??? }` (for a more boring value of `0xdeadbeef`, of course).

It would seem that something is broken, and most likely in the project code - I am aware of this. However, if I create a release build, it runs without errors, and the menu is displayed correctly. Moreover, I edited the menu using the menu editor in Visual C++ 2010, and saved it - there was no change. I'm therefore ruling out menu compatibility issues from the resource being in the wrong format.

I am running Windows XP SP3 on a ThinkPad T61p.

The code that creates the menu is

```
    CMenu menu;
    menu.LoadMenu(RESOURCE_NAME);
    SetMenu(&menu);
```

And runs in the context of a subclass of `CFrameWnd`.

I have searched google a lot and am fairly certain that nobody had this problem before; Also, I'm a newbie to all of C++, MFC and Visual Studio. Help would be immensely appreciated; If I can provide more problem metadata, please tell me and I will do so.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: LoadMenu() has a return value.  A BOOL.  It is not being checked, so of course you don't know why it isn't working properly.

Comment: ASSERT is a debug structure and is compiled out in Release. If you click ignore the code should still work as before.

Comment: @graham.reeds, yes, except for the crippling inconvenience that the menu ceases to exist because of the debug popup... I never even saw it in debug mode.
Oh, and I know what an ASSERT is - the thing is, the fact that it fails should probably tell me that something is wrong. I would like to know how to fix whatever that is.

Comment: @Hans Passant, the assertion fails long after the menu is initialized; It fails when the menu is clicked on for the first time. And a BOOL can only tell me that something supposedly went wrong; When it _works_ in release mode. Whether it gives me 0 or 1, I don't really gain that much information. But thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Well, that's why they used an assert of course.  You got basically two shots at this, first from the function return value, again from the assert.  Then when you built the Release version, they shrugged and said "he didn't seem to care, it must not be important".  Fix the menu.  We can't tell you how to fix the menu, you didn't say anything about it.

Comment: @Hans Passant, I checked, according to `LoadMenu`, the menu is loaded correctly.
And I really don't know what to fix :/ As I said, the menu itself is a resource.

Comment: What other message handlers are on the window that hosts the menu? Is there a faulty `UPDATE_COMMAND_UI` handler? Any other code that relates to the IDs of the commands in the menu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/177ay1x0.aspx)

CMenu::LoadMenu() requires a parameter to be passed in, which is missing in your sample code.
Do check on that and make sure you are passing a valid menu resource id.

Edit:

Your menu object is constructed on the stack and will be destroyed once it went out of scope.
Where are you calling your CWnd::SetMenu from ? You need to make sure the object lifespan can last until the next CWnd::SetMenu else you will be holding/referring a dangling pointer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - something _is_ being passed though, my "<RESOURCE_NAME>" was filtered. My fail.

Comment: Are you sure the menu instance must continue to exist? Its members may be copied by SetMenu.

Comment: Based on the statement : "SetMenu will not destroy a previous menu. An application should call the CMenu::DestroyMenu member function to accomplish this task." I can assure you, they doesn't copy it :)

Comment: @Ryan: No, the CMenu object must exist. SetMenu doesnt copy it.

Comment: You are right of course, I feel really stupid right now. It works now, thanks for the help!
To be more concrete:  I turned the menu into a member of my Window class, and did
`BOOL success=m_Menu.LoadMenu(IDR_MENU1); SetMenu(&m_Menu);`.